# Automatic DNS resolution of my laptop hostname to it's private IP

Tags: networking, dns, docker, dnsmasq

I have a laptop configured with hostname (i.e. mycomputer.mynetwork)
I would like this hostname to resolve to the private IP of this laptop. Not 127.0.0.1, I would it to resolve to the private IP the network is giving me. And I would like this to be automatically updated when I connect to another network.

The ultimate goal is that other docker container running on this computer can resolve mycomputer.mynetwork correctly and automatically.

Is this possible? I looked at dnsmasq without much luck.

Comment: Doesn't Docker set up an internal network completely independent from your LAN?

Comment: Yes, correct, I could use this to address the host from the containers. Yet, if someone knows how to do that with dnsmasq or something that would be great